# dropdown close after 10 seconds

Tags: jquery

I have a problem.

```
$(function () {
             $('.drop-down').click(function(e){
                $('.nav-fixed').toggleClass('open');
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
        });
```

I want when mouseout from #nav.nav-fixed.open the nav close after 10 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(function () {
    $('.drop-down').click(function(e){
        clearTimeout($(this).data('cleartimer'))
        $('.nav-fixed').toggleClass('open');
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('.drop-down').mouseleave(function(){
        var id = setTimeout(function(){
            $('.nav-fixed').removeClass('open');
        }, 10000);
        $(this).data('cleartimer', id);
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j6KFj/)